# Resize tinymce instance on window resize

Tags: javascript, resize, window, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have the following javascript code:

```
var editor = new tinymce.Editor(id, settings);
```

On window resize, I'd like to resize the editor. I've tried to call

```
editor.execCommand("mceResize");
```

but appearantly it doesn't work. I have also tried enabling and disabling it, by calling

```
tinymce.execCommand('removeAddControl', true, id);
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, id);
```

However, the "added" control isn't added with the same settings as those settings originally passed to `new tinymce.editor()`;

Any suggestions on how to make this work are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set relative size?

```
 tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "textareas",
                width : "100%",
                height : "800",
                theme : "advanced",
                plugins : "preview,table,fullpage,jqueryinlinepopups",
                plugin_preview_width : "100%",
                plugin_preview_height : "600",

                ...

            });
```

Comment: If I had enough points I'd check this as answered. Thank you for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Resizing of the editor just got recently fixed. I suggest you download the newest version of tinymce.